# Leaflet convert lat and lng to coords

Tags: javascript, math, leaflet

I have a slite issue that I'm trying to resolve. I've found this function on the internet to convert game coords to lat and lng. However, I'm trying to do the same again but oposit. Essentially get the lat and lng converted to game coords. I've tried everything and no matter what I do I'm not smart enough to figure out the calculations. Hopefully there is some big brain person out here that can help me out.

Original Source Code

```js
game_1_x = -4230,
game_1_y = 8420,
game_2_x = 370,
game_2_y = -640;
CurrentLayer.options.tileSize = 1024

function convertToMap(e, t) {
    var n = 3 * CurrentLayer.options.tileSize,
    i = 2 * CurrentLayer.options.tileSize,
    r = Map.unproject([0, 0], 0),
    o = Map.unproject([i / 2, n - CurrentLayer.options.tileSize], 0),
    s = r.lng + ((e - game_1_x) * (r.lng - o.lng)) / (game_1_x - game_2_x),
    a = r.lat + ((t - game_1_y) * (r.lat - o.lat)) / (game_1_y - game_2_y);
    return (result = { lat: a, lng: s });
}

convertToMap(0, 0); // > {lat: -1903.3289183222957, lng: 941.6347826086957}
```

Comment: Providing details about the `Map.unproject` function, such as API reference and latest implementation of it, might help you and others in finding an answer to this.

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-unproject from my understanding converts the data into LAT and LNG format?

Answer (score 0):

You are only applying the leaflet conversion functions to fixed coordinates. The function arguments then get fed to a linear interpolation.

The general form of a linear interpolation looks a bit like this. Suppose you have a value `a` ranging between `a1` and `a2` and you want to map that to output range `b1` to `b2` then you do

```
b = b1 + (a - a1) * (b2 - b1) / (a2 - a1)
```

You can easily check that for input `a=a1` you get output `b=b1` and for input `a=a2` you get output `b=b2`.

You have similar formulas in your function. You have two changes to the order in the differences, which in my opinion make things a little bit less intuitive but cancel each other out.

```
b = b1 + (a - a1) * (b1 - b2) / (a1 - a2)
```

In case of your two linear interpolation you have

```
a:  e        t
a1: game_1_x game_1_y
a2: game_2_x game_2_y
b1: r.lng    r.lat
b2: o.lng    o.lat
b:  s        a
```

Now to reverse this computation, just swap the roles of `a` and `b`:

```
a = a1 + (b - b1) * (a2 - a1) / (b2 - b1)
```

Note that this answers your question of how to invert your given function. Whether that's a good idea is a completely different question, and depends to a large part on how big a fraction of the globe your map represents. Linear interpolation essentially corresponds to [equirectangular map projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection). For small maps of e.g. a single city that's fine. For large maps of e.g. a large country that very likely would be a poor choice. And if you are using leaflet then chances are you are also using some map tile information which already has a specific projection method and it's not equirectangular ([implementation](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/tree/main/src/geo/projection) suggests different Mercator projections). So you should match that.

Which means the obvious thing to do would be to us a single `unproject` call, and in the inverse operation do a `project` call instead. If you need to account for a change in map position and/or scale, do the linear interpolation on the Cartesian coordinates, not on the latitude and longitude. Specifically, it looks like you want to map the range `game_1_x … game_2_x` to `0 … i/2 = tileSize` and the range `game_1_y … game_2_y` to `0 … (n - tileSize) = 2*tileSize`.